# How to get all files with xml extension placed in resources of springboot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, classpath, resource-loading

I have a spring-boot application and I want to collect all XML files which are placed in the `/src/main/resources` directory which follows a structure as given below :

```
-resources
   -files
      -dir1
        -dir11
           a.xml
           b.xml
      -dir2
        -dir21
          c.xml
      -dir3
        -dir31
          d.xml
```

I have tried few solutions like using `ResourceUtils.getFile`, `ClassPathResource`, `ResourcePatternResolver`, `ClassLoader` but these only work when I am running my application in IDE and dont work if I package my application as jar and deploy it.
I get below exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [files] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system:
```

Directory names (dir1 , dir11 , dir2 etc) and file names (a.xml, b.xml) are not fixed and so not known in code.

These directories and files can have any names.

`resources/files` is the only known directory and I want to collect all xml files inside this directory and its subdirectory.

I have tried almost all solutions found on net, but nothing seems to work for my use-case.

How can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

You can fetch the known directory `files` and recursively list all the `File[]` objects.

It would be easier if you user `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(File directory, String[] extensions, boolean recursive);`

I've created a helper function like below to wrap the logic of `String.format` and `classpath:`

```
public static File getResourceAsFile(String relativeFilePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return ResourceUtils.getFile(String.format("classpath:%s",relativeFilePath));

}
```

And to use it,

```
String relativeFilePath ="files";

File file =getResourceAsFile(relativeFilePath);


Collection<File> files=FileUtils.listFiles(file,null,true); //
```

And if you want to read all the `xml` files, then pass second parameter as

```
Collection<File> files=FileUtils.listFiles(file,new String[]{"xml"},true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mansoor for help. But in my case , names of directories and files inside 'files' directory are not fixed, and so I cant hardocode in code. I have edited the question for same.

Comment: You can read the files in a directory once you've a reference to the known directory - in your case it is "./resources/files".